# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, exception

why when running the program after a few minutes an error appears as I attached below. Please have a solution

Thanks

[image: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll]
[image: path in bunfu textbox]

Comment: This is what usually happens when you have an unhandled exception, it bubbles upstream. The exception suggests that you're trying to draw something or with something - an image, or you're using a Brush or Pen - that is null or disposed (or which has incorrect values) at that time. You should post that code

Comment: @Jimi , I only use the image path in bunifu textbox

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. That's a string. In a TextBox. What are you doing with a string in a TextBox? How do you use that information, in a way that ends up causing an exception in a graphic library? -- As mentioned, that exception means that you're passing an invalid object to drawing method

Comment: @Jimi , I use it as logo information to process reports with bunifu report

Comment: Still doesn't mean anything. You need to show code that reproduces this behavior. Hence, you have to debug your app to find out when this exception is generated and what is wrong at that time, then post the results of your observations here (if you still need help fixing the issue at that point)